# Add a blueprint to Confluence visible on JIRA Service Desk

Tags: jira, confluence

On JIRA Service Desk an operator can write a Confluence page to save the knowledge of the support. when he clics to add the article there are 2 templates that are showing up. How can we edit / add templates to this list? 
thanks a lot 
best 
AK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you can only use How-To and Troubleshooting templates. However, Atlassian has an open feature request for this: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSD-3160

Comment: If you don't need the How-To and Troubleshooting, maybe you can try and edit those templates in Confluence and change them base on your need. Haven't tried it but you can give it a shot as a workaround :-) They are in General Configuration > Blueprints and Template